# How can we calculate AIC from a negative binomial GLMM?

Tags: r, aic, glmm, negative-binomial-distribution, bic

Our problem here described is to calculate AIC from a GLMM negbin.
Our data compose by 2 Categorical variables (Yes/Not), 3 Numerical variables and our random factor, all without any NA.
We want to create a GLMM model with negative binomial family and this model calculates AIC and BIC as NA, but calculate the rest of the model values. In R:

**>model<-glmmPQL(X~Categorical1*Categorical2+Numerical1+Numerical2+Numerical3,random=~1|Random1,family=negative.binomial(theta = 1234, link = "log"),data=Data)**

**>summary(model)**

**Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood**

**Data: Data**

**AIC BIC logLik**

**NA  NA   NA**

We tried using in R: AIC(model), AIC(logLik(model)), BIC(model), BIC(logLik(model)) & extractAIC(model) with NA as a result (in the case of extractAIC we obtain 9 NA). How can we calculate this AIC?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

If you want the marginal AIC (i.e., for the implied marginal model that focuses on the fixed effects alone), you can fit the model with the [**GLMMadaptive**](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) package that provides this in the output of the `summary()` method. E.g., check [this example](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/reference/negative_binomial.html).

If you want the conditional AIC that focuses on selecting both the fixed and random effects, check the [**cAIC4**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=cAIC4) package.